# Django ORM Optimal solution for bulk stock data store?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

i am working on django project in my project i am have created  models product,branch,stock i and one of database server there to i am fetch 400 000 records of stock data and storing in my project database but problem is i am storing through orm its taking 50 min to storing 400 000 records is there best solution to reduce the time. you can see below model class which i am storing stock data.

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: What is a "lac" or "lack" ?

Comment: @FrankHeikens As far as I know, "lac" and "lakh" (not lack, that's probably autocorrect...) is an Indian word for 100 000. Arvind, please don't use Indian words here since all people are not from India.